# Prisma - Link user and likes

Tags: backend, prisma

I'm currently facing some challenges with Prisma and backend development, and despite spending two days searching, I haven't found a solution that addresses my needs.

I'm trying to implement functionality to track users who have liked a post. Specifically, I want to associate each post with a "likedBy" field that contains the IDs of users who liked it. Additionally, I'd like to create a "likedPosts" field for users, which would list all the posts a user has liked, identified by their postIds.

The goal is to be able to count the number of likes a post has received and identify which posts a user has liked. This is all part of a backend programming project using Prisma.

I have this current modele. I tried a lot of other but no one work as expected :

I have this prisma model :

```
model Post {
    id              String   @id @default(cuid())
    title           String
    postDescription String
    content         String?
    image           String?
    published       Boolean  @default(false)
    createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt       DateTime @updatedAt
    author          User?    @relation("UserPosts", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
    likedBy         User[]   @relation("PostLikes")
    authorId        String?



    tags      Tag[]  @relation("PostTags")
} 

model User {
    id            String    @id @default(cuid())
    name          String?
    email         String?   @unique
    emailVerified DateTime? @map("email_verified")
    image         String?
    createdAt     DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
    updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
    posts         Post[]    @relation("UserPosts")
    likedPosts    Post[]    @relation("PostLikes")
    accounts      Account[]
    sessions      Session[]
    role          String    @default("USER")


    @@map(name: "users")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You prisma model looks good for an implicit many-to-many relation.

In your posts query, you would do something like this:

```
const posts = await prisma.posts.findMany({
  include: {
    _count: {
      select: { likedBy: true }, //Or PostLikes? Not sure. returns number of likes
    },
  },
})
```

I haven't tested, but I think that you can also do this for findUnique query

Check some more docs for count: [Prisma docs for count](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/aggregation-grouping-summarizing#count)
and for implicit relations: [Prisma docs for implicit relation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations)

Comment: My current problème is that I can’t add values in liked by or likedPosts :/

Comment: What kind of values would you like to store inside likedPosts?